# how to log activeadmin related errors to seperate log file in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am  seperating the production logs into diffferent files like api_calls, activeadmin logs and sql logs and rest other logs.in rails environment. can this be possible . please have look at this .

I have tried using `activeadmin-logs` gem.
but didnt got the result.

Comment: Did you mean errors that occurred activeadmin resource files?

Comment: yes...I want to seperate the all logs related to active admin resources in seperate file

Comment: can we do that all the logs related to activeadmin resource be logged seperately in custom logfile ?

Comment: as far as i know there is no gem or library available for this. But, you can write a custom logger and include in activeadmin resources and log errors into it.

Comment: can you please tell me how include custom logger in to activeadmin resources